# Best practices to check SSL Certificate validity on client side in QWebSockets

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, websocket, qtwebsockets

I'm trying to write an application which uses the brand new QWebSockets.

So far, I want to implement the secure web socket, but the examples point me to reject SSL errors, even if they have commented that it is unsafe.

My question is: how should I handle the controls on SSL certificates, even self-signed ones, on client side? What are the best practices in this case?

FYI, here there's [a link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsslerror.html) to QSSLErrors which are emitted by the QWebSocket class .

Unfortunately, webSocket.sslConfiguration().peerCertificate() returns empty values when I'm printing them out.

Answer (score 0):

Very broad, but you shouldn't trust all certificates, or bypass hostname checking in HTTPS. You don't need to verify the certificate itself, as the library should do that. You should also check that the subjectDN of the certificate is the one you're expecting to see, unless you're using HTTPS which does that for you (hostname check).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Basically, WebSockets are interpreted as HTTP requests (in my case, as HTTPS).
The hostname check can be easily done, but QWebSockets doesn't allow me to verify the content of the certificate itself.